# "Reference to undefined setting" error with custom task using a custom configuration in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to create a task in sbt that will output the full classpath of a custom Configuration, but I get `an undefined setting error` when sbt tries to load the project definition. I can't figure out which setting has to be defined:

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object FoobarBuild extends Build {
  lazy val ZK = config("zk")
  lazy val fcp = TaskKey[String]("fcp", "create formatted classpath")
  lazy val fcpTask = fcp <<= (fullClasspath in ZK) map { cp =>
    println(cp.files.absString)
    cp.files.absString
  }

  lazy val project = Project("foobar", file(".")).
    configs(ZK).
    settings(
      name := "foobar",
      version := "1.0",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
    ).
    settings(fcpTask)
}
```

Error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from foobar/project
Reference to undefined setting:

  zk:fullClasspath from *:fcp (/Users/gaston/mesosphere/foobar/project/Build.scala:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

`zk:fullClasspath` on the 7th line of this file is, of course, `fullClasspath in ZK`. It's undefined because it isn't set or inherited from any other config, I believe.